# Slow to get element with TestStack.White

Tags: c#, ui-automation, white-framework, teststack

So what I'm doing is using the `.Exist<T>` method in TestStack.White to see if an error dialog box exists. The problem I'm having is that finding it is EXTREMELY slow. This is due to the fact the the program has a data table in it with over 400 items, and then sub items of those items. I'm not really sure how I can make this search quicker, here's the box I'm trying to see if exists:

[Dialog Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNITD.png)

And here is the information on it:

```
"No Rates Returned":
How found: Selected from tree...
Name: "No rates returned."
ControlType: UIA_TextControlTypeId (0xC364)
LocalizedControlType: "text"
BoundingRectangle: {l:1635 t:462 r:1731 b:477}
IsEnabled: true
IsOffscreen: false
IsKeyboardFocusable: false
HasKeyboardFocus: false
AccessKey: ""
ProcessId: 3036
RuntimeId: [2A.6105AE]
AutomationId: "65535"
FrameworkId: "Win32"
ClassName: "Static"
NativeWindowHandle: 0x6105AE
ProviderDescription: "[pid:10424,providerId:0x6105AE Main:Nested [pid:3036,providerId:0x6105AE Annotation(parent link):Microsoft: Annotation Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll); Main:Microsoft: MSAA Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll)]; Hwnd(parent link):Microsoft: HWND Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll)]"
IsPassword: false
HelpText: ""
HeadingLevel: [Not supported]
LegacyIAccessible.ChildId: 0
LegacyIAccessible.DefaultAction: ""
LegacyIAccessible.Description: ""
LegacyIAccessible.Help: ""
LegacyIAccessible.KeyboardShortcut: ""
LegacyIAccessible.Name: "No rates returned."
LegacyIAccessible.Role: text (0x29)
LegacyIAccessible.State: read only (0x40)
LegacyIAccessible.Value: ""
IsAnnotationPatternAvailable: false
IsDragPatternAvailable: false
IsDockPatternAvailable: false
IsDropTargetPatternAvailable: false
IsExpandCollapsePatternAvailable: false
IsGridItemPatternAvailable: false
IsGridPatternAvailable: false
IsInvokePatternAvailable: false
IsItemContainerPatternAvailable: false
IsLegacyIAccessiblePatternAvailable: true
IsMultipleViewPatternAvailable: false
IsObjectModelPatternAvailable: false
IsRangeValuePatternAvailable: false
IsScrollItemPatternAvailable: false
IsScrollPatternAvailable: false
IsSelectionItemPatternAvailable: false
IsSelectionPatternAvailable: false
IsSpreadsheetItemPatternAvailable: false
IsSpreadsheetPatternAvailable: false
IsStylesPatternAvailable: false
IsSynchronizedInputPatternAvailable: false
IsTableItemPatternAvailable: false
IsTablePatternAvailable: false
IsTextChildPatternAvailable: false
IsTextEditPatternAvailable: false
IsTextPatternAvailable: false
IsTextPattern2Available: false
IsTogglePatternAvailable: false
IsTransformPatternAvailable: false
IsTransform2PatternAvailable: false
IsValuePatternAvailable: false
IsVirtualizedItemPatternAvailable: false
IsWindowPatternAvailable: false
IsCustomNavigationPatternAvailable: false
IsSelectionPattern2Available: false
FirstChild: [null]
LastChild: [null]
Next: [null]
Previous: "OK" button
Other Props: Object has no additional properties
Children: Container has no children
Ancestors: "" dialog
 "New Car  " window
 "Desktop 1" pane
 [ No Parent ]
```

Dialog box (itself):

```
How found: Selected from tree...
Name: ""
ControlType: UIA_WindowControlTypeId (0xC370)
LocalizedControlType: "dialog"
BoundingRectangle: {l:1621 t:413 r:1764 b:543}
IsEnabled: true
IsKeyboardFocusable: true
HasKeyboardFocus: false
ProcessId: 3036
RuntimeId: [2A.7109FC]
FrameworkId: "Win32"
ClassName: "#32770"
NativeWindowHandle: 0x7109FC
IsControlElement: true
IsContentElement: true
ProviderDescription: "[pid:10424,providerId:0x7109FC Main:Microsoft: Container Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll); Nonclient:Microsoft: Non-Client Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll); Hwnd(parent link):Microsoft: HWND Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll)]"
HeadingLevel: [Not supported]
LegacyIAccessible.ChildId: 0
LegacyIAccessible.Role: dialog (0x12)
LegacyIAccessible.State: focusable (0x100000)
Transform.CanMove: true
Transform.CanResize: false
Transform.CanRotate: false
Window.CanMaximize: false
Window.CanMinimize: false
Window.IsModal: true
Window.IsTopmost: false
Window.WindowInteractionState: ReadyForUserInteraction (2)
Window.WindowVisualState: Normal (0)
IsAnnotationPatternAvailable: false
IsDragPatternAvailable: false
IsDockPatternAvailable: false
IsDropTargetPatternAvailable: false
IsExpandCollapsePatternAvailable: false
IsGridItemPatternAvailable: false
IsGridPatternAvailable: false
IsInvokePatternAvailable: false
IsItemContainerPatternAvailable: false
IsLegacyIAccessiblePatternAvailable: true
IsMultipleViewPatternAvailable: false
IsObjectModelPatternAvailable: false
IsRangeValuePatternAvailable: false
IsScrollItemPatternAvailable: false
IsScrollPatternAvailable: false
IsSelectionItemPatternAvailable: false
IsSelectionPatternAvailable: false
IsSpreadsheetItemPatternAvailable: false
IsSpreadsheetPatternAvailable: false
IsStylesPatternAvailable: false
IsSynchronizedInputPatternAvailable: false
IsTableItemPatternAvailable: false
IsTablePatternAvailable: false
IsTextChildPatternAvailable: false
IsTextEditPatternAvailable: false
IsTextPatternAvailable: false
IsTextPattern2Available: false
IsTogglePatternAvailable: false
IsTransformPatternAvailable: true
IsTransform2PatternAvailable: false
IsValuePatternAvailable: false
IsVirtualizedItemPatternAvailable: false
IsWindowPatternAvailable: true
IsCustomNavigationPatternAvailable: false
IsSelectionPattern2Available: false
FirstChild: "OK" button
LastChild: "No rates returned." text
Next: "Deductible" pane
Previous: [null]
Other Props: Object has no additional properties
Children: "OK" button
 "No rates returned." text
Ancestors: "New Car  " window
 "Desktop 1" pane
 [ No Parent ]
```

And here is the code I'm using to pull it:

```
private bool GrabErrorOrExucute()
        {
            using (CoreAppXmlConfiguration.Instance.ApplyTemporarySetting(s => s.BusyTimeout = 500))
            {
                if (_mainWindow.Exists(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("65535")))
                {
                    var error = _mainWindow.Get(
                        SearchCriteria
                            .ByAutomationId(
                                "65535")); 
                    MessageBox.Show("Error has been thrown while getting rates, it will be displayed now...",
                        "Error While Getting Rates", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error,
                        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
                    MessageBox.Show(error.Name, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error,
                        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);


                    var okbtn = _mainWindow.Get<Button>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("2"));
                    ratestat.Text = "Error While Getting Rate...";
                    Stop();
                    return true;
                }


                return false;
            }
        }
```

This can take well over 10-15 minutes minutes because of the table that is in the program. Here's what the table looks like (Which goes from 1 to ~400). How do I make this faster?:

[Window with table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzRUT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:
`CoreAppXmlConfiguration.Instance.RawElementBasedSearch = true;`
somewhere before test.
 Another option is to limit search depth:
`CoreAppXmlConfiguration.Instance.RawElementBasedSearch = true;`

For me theese two aproaches allow good performance compared to default